# Do the Russian Army "probably" have a unit shooting soldiers attempting to retreat?

Tags: russo-ukrainian-war

A recent Times (UK) article reported that the British Ministry of Defence stated that the Russian Army may have units instructed to fire on Russian soldiers attempting to retreat during the current war in Ukraine, a tactic reminiscent of WW2.

Unfortunately it's behind a paywall, but the "readable" preview bit states...

> Russia’s army has “probably” instructed special units to fire on retreating soldiers in Ukraine in an echo of Stalinist practice during the Second World War, the Ministry of Defence has claimed.
>
> “Due to low morale and reluctance to fight, Russian forces have probably started deploying ‘barrier troops’ or ‘blocking units’,” it said in an intelligence update. “These units threaten to shoot their own retreating soldiers in order to compel offensives and have been used in previous conflicts by Russian forces.”
>
> [Retreating Russian soldiers may be shot, says MoD](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/retreating-russian-soldiers-may-be-shot-says-mod-g69bsbg58)

The Ministry of Defence [tweeted](https://twitter.com/DefenceHQ/status/1588418427944898561) a similar claim:

> [image: Due to low morale and reluctance to fight, Russian forces have probably started deploying "barrier troops" or "blocking units". These units threaten to shoot their own retreating soldiers (...)]

However, when someone says "probably" they can often mean anything from just themselves supposing as far as having evidence that this is very likely.

A search around the 'net reveals articles stating different levels of certainty but pointing back to the same "probably" quote from the MOD, without offering any further evidence.

So my question is, is there anything other than this quote, or any elaboration on this quote (or what is meant by "probably" in this case) to indicate the likelihood that Russia are shooting their own retreating soldiers?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of unknown information about this and it will likely be a while before much is learned about it.

Comment: The primary source for this statement would be the official UK MoD social media news channel ([link to the twitter post](https://twitter.com/DefenceHQ/status/1588418427944898561?s=20&t=TRimBV29J0JXuoy6cJXURg)). There's basically no additional information there, though. Other "intelligence update" posts there sometimes provide the sources for their info (mostly statements by Ukrainian officials), but otherwise it all seems to be "unconfirmed", "likely" and "probably".

Comment: I am trying to understand the question. You aren't looking for evidence that the MoD did/didn't make the claim, right? Are you looking for evidence for/against that retreating Russian soldiers have been shot at by fellow troops? That Russian soldiers have been threatened? That Russian soldiers have been issued orders? I'm worried the claim seems far softer: "We reckon that's just the sort of thing our enemies would do."

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't doubt that the MoD made the claim. I'm sceptical about the claim itself. I believe it coming from the MoD and the fact that it has spread throughout the news media (in the west at least) makes it "notable" as far as this site is concerned. However, the word "probably" - a very woolly term IMHO - and the lack of corroborating evidence makes the claim very concerning, especially given that same spread throughout the media. So I'm wondering if any such evidence exists, or, OTOH, if it comes to light some time in the future, this question can be answered at that point.

Comment: To summarise, possible answers would be either evidence that it is (or is not) happening or evidence that it is "probably" - as in, there is a high likelihood of it - happening, or even clarification of the MoD's assessed probability of it happening.

Comment: @komodosp: There is still murkiness: First is the difference between "Retreating troops have been shot.", "Retreating troops have been warned that they will be shot." and "Some troops have been ordered to shoot any retreating troops." Which do you mean?

Comment: The second is the wishy-washiness of the MoD. This looks awfully like the "probably" is coming from their judgement of how they think their enemy behaves, based on 70 year old data. I applaud your skepticism, because it sounds like empty, one-sided propaganda. I am struggling on how we can answer the question if the MoD are only claiming it is "probably" true based on their own speculations and models  - if they had direct evidence, they would have worded it differently, and if they don't have direct evidence, we aren't likely to be able to find it. Tricky.

Comment: Just a hat-tip to the MOD's circular logic:  Low morale/discipline implies that they are shooting deserters, which implies that they have low morale/discipline.

Comment: @Oddthinking The trouble with judging the MOD position is that it could be based on intelligence evidence they can't share readily. I think the spirit of the question is whether there is other evidence that is available that might corroborate the claim. And in this war where many pieces of video evidence have been shared and where the Russians are often communicating on social media, that evidence might well exist.

Comment: It's very vague. The Russian army, like all militaries, employs people whose job is to catch deserters, with at least typical law enforcement powers to shoot people resisting arrest, possessing illegal guns, etc. But does this mean units over and above normal enforcement? Or does it mean increased patrols by those whose job it normally is? Or a change in the rules of engagement to allow shooting suspected deserters? Or something else?

Comment: There have been intercepted calls from Russian soldiers to people at home who have made this claim. But this just kicks the claim down the road a little. See, for example @wartranslated (twitter)